# "WinError 2 - The system cannot find the file specified" when trying to run script in Sublime Text

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, sublimetext

I get this error when trying to run Python on Sublime Text. I think I've screwed up all the path variables.

Python is already installed and this is the Build System:

```
{
     "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file")
}
```

Error:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[path: C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\;C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\;C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\]
```

These are the screenshots of the environment variables:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, the problem are not the variables but the Build System.

I changed to:

```
{
   "cmd": ["python", "$file"]
}
```

and now it's working properly.

I don't know what "-u" means so I avoided.

Comment: You can look-up what the various command-line arguments mean in the fine [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u).